# Why I'm getting error using pattern with HTML5

Tags: html

I'm doing a form in HTML5 and I receive an error message that says:"match the requested format" and I don't know why, I attach the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombres" required pattern="[a-z]">
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" required pattern="[a-z]">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: If you're going to add an image, please crop that down to the relevant part of the page - that's almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) only allow for one lower case character.

If you want that to be multiple characters, you'd need to add a `+` sign:

```
pattern="[a-z]+"
```

(Technically, since the fields are marked as `required`, an asterisk (`*`) would serve the same purpose.)